# Windows 7 external 2.5 hard drive read write permissions format

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, permissions

Working with Windows 7 professional. While trying to format western digital 250GB sata laptop drive; receiving error not initialized. Went to elevated command line to diskpart to clean all; received error message write protected. Went to Disk Management & Virtual disk drive shows as disk 2 not initialized. No format options available greyed out. Went back to command line tried to see attributes disk is read only. How do I take owner ship to change the permissions & format.

Comment: Can you connect it to another PC, see if it can be formatted there?

Answer (score 0):

As administrator, you can right click the file and select

```
Properties, Security, Advanced, Owner
```

Also see:

http://www.windows-it.tk/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=16

http://forum.soft32.com/windows/Setting-Permissions-Hard-Drive-ftopict352902.html

Answer (score 0):

Boot from your Windows installation media into a recovery prompt and run DISKPART from there, generally it should clean things up for you without much trouble.

If that fails, I'd use a Linux live CD like Ubuntu Desktop and use the partitioning tools included to work with the drive; I've found in the past that sometimes the Linux partitioning tools are more robust than their Windows counterparts.